# A question involving polynomials and sine

Tags: real-analysis

The question is to show that if $f(x)$ is an odd degree polynomial function, then $f(x)=\sin(x)$ has a real root.  My thought is to let $h(x)=f(x)-\sin(x)$ and show that a root exists.  Intuitively the range of $h(x)$ is $\mathbb{R}$, but I am having a hard time with a formal proof.  I would like to invoke the Intermediate Value Theorem, but am getting a little lost in construction.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you explain for me what is an odd degree polynomial function?

Comment: Maybe I worded that poorly, but I mean a function such as $k_3x^3+k_2x^2+kx+k_0,\;\; k_i \in \mathbb{R}$.  That is, any polynomial whose greatest power is odd.

Comment: O, I see! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $h$ the function defined by $h(x)=f(x)-\sin x$ so $h$ is continuous and since $f$ has odd degree then
$$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}h(x)=\pm\infty\; \text{or}\; \mp\infty$$
and we use the intermediate value theorem to conclude.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Would you mind giving your proof? Just so I can 'proofread' mine?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Root Existing Theorem:

> Try to prove that there exists $M, N \in \Bbb R$, $(f(N)-\sin N) \times (f(M)-\sin M) < 0 $

Comment: do you mean arithmetic multiplication or composition multiplication?